# Can Date Field have only Month & Year

Tags: apex, visualforce, datetime, date, calendar

I am trying to get Attendance Records where Date's are in selected month. I have create picklist on VF page for months and year, but this doesn't seem logically true !

I think that we should have Calender (which we get opened when we click on Date type field) which will be having only a Month and Year.

So can we do this, if yes then how it should be ?????

Comment: Check out this hack to do it via jquery on a VF page:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only

Comment: Could you create a custom component to pick the month/year? Essentially you are still working with a Date object, but you are hiding the day portion (maybe assume a value of 1).

Answer (score 1):

Without using @Ray Dehler suggestion to use a jQuery hack, I think you'd need to try creating a dependent picklist which would wind up being another hack of sorts, especially if you needed the data to still be in proper Date Format.

If you did that, you'd end up where you had a final multi-select picklist (for days) where the values would then need to be assembled with year and month using a formula to put them into date format. I don't think that would be a very efficient use of the database nor would it be particularly user friendly.